# chromosome 19 and recombination

Tags: genetics, chromosome, human-genome, recombination

Im doing a project with structural variation created by recombination within the human genome during spermatogenesis, where im especially examining intrachromatid homolog recombination.

I find that chromosome 19 is less prone to recombine and form strutural variation. I know that chromosome 19 has a high gene density and have a high amount of linked genes, so a low CentiMorgan unit. But some articles, states that chromosome 19 contains duplicated regions, which i would assume would be prone to recombine with intrachromatid recombination.

So my question is, from an evolutionary perspective, does anyone know any articles, which might describe why chr 19 is less likely to recombine. if chromosome 19 have a higher amount of life essential genes, or is it simply the high density between the repeats which affects the recombination (so sort of like heterchromatin structures).

I've looked and cannot find any results to support that chromosome 19 are "more different" when compared to other autosomes. As an example chromosome 1 has a higher CentiMorgan unit and are thus more likely to recombine, so "it" handles structural variations better, but it still contains important genes.

Thanks for your help.